# How to pass a vector to a function by value in C

Tags: c

I want to pass a vector to a function by value (not by reference). After exectuting the code arr[1], arr[2] and arr[3] are equal 0. What arguments should the fuction `getAvarage` have to not modifey vector `arr`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double getAverage(int v[]);
int main()
{
    int arr[4], i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        printf("arr[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("avrg=%lf", getAverage(arr));
    printf("\n%d %d %d", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    return 0;
}

double getAverage(int v[])
{

    int i;
    double avg;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
       sum += v[i];
       v[i] = 0;
    }
   avg = sum / 4;
   return avg;
}
```

Comment: Note, that the terminology is wrong. There is no such thing as a vector in the [tag:c] programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays decay to a pointer to their first element when passed to a function. This is a convenience feature. There are a few similar cases - functions decay to a pointer to the function when passed, almost anything decays to a `bool` in a conditional statement. It's just a case of learning these as you go.

There is a solution of sorts to passing an array by value. An instance of a struct will be passed by value, so putting the array in a struct will achieve the desired result.

```
struct demo
{
  int some_array[4];
};

void i_cant_change_it(struct demo x)
{
  x.some_array[0] = 42;
}
```

This is because the struct instance, fortunately, doesn't decay to a pointer when passed to a function. If you want to be able to mutate the instance, such that the caller can see the change, the prototype looks like

```
void i_might_change_it(struct demo *);
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a misuse of features. You just have to learn to work with it. You don't say anything but this is inefficient, there is no reason to copy an array if you are not going to modify it, this is a anti-pattern. The OP code, doesn't need to modify the array so making a copy of it is simply inefficient, because it's not necessary.

Comment: There are good reasons to copy the array. Alias analysis is one. Predictable behaviour at the call site is another - I know the function won't mutate my copy, because it can't. The compiler is entirely capable of rewriting to pass by pointer if it helps. Array decay is an obsolete performance optimisation or an inconsistency introduced for ease of use. It's not an advantage.

Comment: If you really need to copy the array you should, but from the posted code there appears to be no need. If the posted code is an attempt of a minimal sample of code that reproduces the problem, it's terrible. Because there is no logical reason to set the values to `0` in the `getAverage()` function. So I think, if this is the answer the OP was looking for that is not the question they should have asked.

Answer (score 4):

In c, you cannot pass a variable by reference. It's always by value. The problem is that arrays, are converted into pointers to their first element, so you can modify the original object through the pointer inside the function.

If you want to ensure that the function will not alter the contents of the array you can use the `const` keyword. It will not strictly prevent you from modifying the object, but it helps detecting unintended modification.

```
double getAverage(const int *v);
```

You can use another `const` to avoid reassigning the pointer value too

```
double getAverage(const int *const v);
```

That said, there is no good reason to assign `0` to the values inside the `getAverage()` function anyway. So it could be

```
double 
get_average(const int *const v)
{
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
       sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum / 4.0;
}
```

Comment: The second const adds no information to the interface and constrains the implementation. Why include it?

Comment: To prevent reassigning `v` accidentally!